# how do we convert (a ∧ b) ↔ c into CNF form?

Tags: logic

After making a truth table, what I came up with was:

(¬ (a ∧ b ) ∨ c ) ∧ ( (a ∧ b ) ∨ c ) ∧ ( (a ∧ b ) ∨ ¬ c )

But now I find it difficult to convert this into CNF. I have no idea how to change the ∧ such that they become ∨ within the clauses.

What I am doing is using the (a ∧ b) and c to form the CNF. But this is getting me nowhere.

I consulted my coursemates, who said I should instead be using a, b, and c to form the CNF. I think they're right, but I don't know why I am wrong.

Should I be using just the atomic propositions, instead of using the compound proposition? Is this why I am hitting a brick wall here?

If I use the atomic propositions, wouldn't that be a different meaning than using compound proposition (a ∧ b)?

Please help. Thanks so much.

Comment: 1st step) unpack $\leftrightarrow$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(a\land b)\leftrightarrow c$ becomes
$$(a\land b\land c)\lor(\neg a\land\neg c)\lor(\neg b\land\neg c)$$
This is the DNF. To get the CNF we distribute OR over AND, removing combinations containing things like $a\lor\neg a$ and clauses contained in other clauses:
$$(a\lor\neg c)\land(b\lor\neg c)\land(c\lor\neg a\lor\neg b)$$